# Changepoint Analysis in R

Tags: r

I am experimenting with the cpt and bcp packages in R. I import the following data from a CSV file:

[image: Data plot]

Here is the CSV file link: http://www.filedropper.com/cpttest

Running bcp:

```
p.bcp=bcp(p$Rate);
plot(p.bcp)
```

Point 28 is a change point according to bcp.

When running cpt, I get no indication that a change point exists:

```
p.cpt=cpt.mean(p$Rate,method="AMOC")
p.cpt
```

Wondering if anyone could advise why **cpt** does not detect a change point?

Comment: Please consider [making your example reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567) by providing the required data or using other publicly available data set.

Comment: Added a link to the CSV. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See if the [`changepoint` package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v058i03) satisfies your purpose.
Replace the word `method` with `PELT`, `BinSeg`, or `SegNeigh`.

```
library(changepoint)

p.cpt <- changepoint::cpt.mean(p$Rate,method="method")
cpts(p.cpt)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many change point packages in `R` and you could try others. I've [compiled a list here](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html). Disclosure: I am the developer of the `mcp` package.

To use `mcp` for your problem, do:

```r
model = list(
  Rate ~ 1,  # Intercept
  ~ 1  # Another intercept
)

library(mcp)
fit = mcp(model, p)
plot(fit)
```

[image]

See the estimate of the change point (`cp_1`) as well as the other parameters of the model. You could also see it as a narrow blue distribution in the plot above.

```r
summary(fit)

Family: gaussian(link = 'identity')
Iterations: 9000 from 3 chains.
Segments:
  1: Rate ~ 1
  2: Rate ~ 1 ~ 1

Population-level parameters:
    name    mean   lower   upper Rhat n.eff
    cp_1 30.5009 3.0e+01 3.1e+01    1  6250
   int_1  0.0132 1.3e-02 1.3e-02    1  5501
   int_2  0.0071 6.8e-03 7.3e-03    1  5514
 sigma_1  0.0008 6.8e-04 9.4e-04    1  5056
```

Comment: great answer! apparently this package has been removed from cran :(

Comment: @stats555 Yeah, a dependency had incompatible changes and I still haven't fixed it. I'm working on a new version but until then, you can do `remotes::install_github("lindeloev/mcp")` and install an older version of `tidybayes`.

Answer (score 0):

In R, there are many packages available for time series changepoint detection. changepoint is definitely a very useful one. A partial list of the packages is summarized in CRAN Task View:

> Change point detection is provided in strucchange (using linear regression models), and in trend (using nonparametric tests). The changepoint package provides many popular changepoint methods, and ecp does nonparametric changepoint detection for univariate and multivariate series. changepoint.np implements the nonparametric PELT algorithm, while changepoint.mv detects changepoints in multivariate time series. InspectChangepoint uses sparse projection to estimate changepoints in high-dimensional time series. robcp provides robust change-point detection using Huberized cusum tests, and Rbeast provides Bayesian change-point detection and time series decomposition.

Here is also a great blog comparing several alternative packages: https://www.marinedatascience.co/blog/2019/09/28/comparison-of-change-point-detection-methods/. Another impressive comparison is from Dr. Jonas Kristoffer Lindeløv who developed the mcp package: https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html.